# Android - SwitchCompact disable/stop default behaviour

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

In my android project I have [SwitchCompact](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/SwitchCompat.html), `onClick` of which I do networking stuff and on basis response I want to change `SwitchCompact` to checked or not checked.

**The problem I am facing now is :**
   When I click on `SwitchCompact` it changes its status (*ie true to false and vice versa*) which is its normal behaviour. I want to disable its normal/default behaviour.

Is that possible?

```
class MyClass extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    SwitchCompat switchCompact;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //my view inflating stuff
        switchCompact= (SwitchCompat) view.findViewById(R.id.switch_id);
        switchCompact.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if (view.getId()==R.id.switch_id) {
            //make http request
        }
    }

    public void onResponse(Response response){
        switchCompact.setChecked(response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to do that. My suggestion would be to let the switch do its default behaviour. Then you do the network call. If your call is successful leave the switch as such otherwise revert it back and show a SnackBar to user stating what has happened.

Comment: **:)** I have to do that as last resort...

Comment: I have used the same implementation thats why. Did a lot of digging and couldnt find a way to change default behaviour.

Comment: @RageshRamesh check my workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Well putting more pressure on my head I found something like work around, not an exact answer :)

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId()==R.id.switch_id) {
       switchCompact.setChecked(!switchCompact.isChecked());
       //make networking stuff.
    }
 }
```

@RageshRamesh : I was thinking why not revert back its status before response or after `onClick`  i.e. when the Switch changes its status. This workaround works as expected. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to help. And i guess this works. But isn't UI updated multiple times for one click?